# Good `partition` implementation for lazy list?

Tags: ocaml

```
type 'a lazy_list_t = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazy_list_t)
```

What is the best / efficient way to implement `partition` function?

Here is my implementation.

```
let rec filter f (Cons (x, tl_f)) =
  if f x then Cons (x, fun () -> filter f (tl_f()))
  else filter f (tl_f())

let partition f ll = filter f ll, filter (fun x -> f x |> not) ll
```

I think it is simple to read, but the disadvantage is for every element, `f` is applied twice actually.

Any better way?

Comment: You could `map` over the list yielding `[(f v, v), ..]` and then use `filter` twice over that. This would apply `f` only once to each element.

Comment: @DanD. good thought. can you extend your comment to answer so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would work on this:

```
let rec fold_right f ll b =
  match ll with
    [] -> b
  | x :: xs -> f x (fold_right f xs b);;

let partition f ll = 
  let f_split v (tt, ff) = 
    if f v = true then (v::tt,ff) else (tt,v::ff) in 
    fold_right f_split ll ([], []);;
```

so that you can write down a lazy fold_right and eventually a lazy partition function. 
For instance something of the kind:

```
let rec fold_right f (Cons(x, xs)) b =
  f x (fold_right f (xs()) b);;
```

Comment: could you please write a code for lazy partition function?